# Add a special class for the first index page

Tags: blogger

I want to add an `index--first` class for the first page with a `pageType` of index. This can be ***not just the homepage*** (in which case it would be an easy test `data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl`), but also the first page resulting from a keyword search or the first label page.

At this point I have the following code (which works perfectly fine):

```
<body expr:class='(data:blog.pageType) + (data:blog.searchLabel ? " index--label" : "") + (data:blog.searchQuery ? " index--query" : "")'>
  <!-- more stuff here -->
</body>
```

What this does is add an `index` class for all index pages, an `index--label` class for all index pages that are also label pages and an `index--query` class for all index pages that are also search query results.

What I'd still need is to somehow catch a page of type `index` that doesn't contain `updated-max` in the URL and add the `index--first` class on it.

This doesn't work, I get an "invalid expression" error:

```
<body expr:class='(data:blog.pageType == "index" ? ("index" + (data:blog.url.indexOf("updated-max") != -1 ? " index--home" : "")) : "") + (data:blog.searchLabel ? " index--label" : "") + (data:blog.searchQuery ? " index--query" : "")'>
</body>
```

So what's the correct way to do it?

I am not looking for a JavaScript solution, the use of `indexOf()` was just a wild guess on my part (sadly, a wild guess is my best bet as Blogger resources are limited) and not an attempt to use JavaScript in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```xml
<body expr:class='data:blog.pageType'>
  <b:class cond='data:view.search.label' name='index--label'/>
  <b:class cond='data:view.search.query' name='index--query'/>
  <b:class cond='data:view.isMultipleItems and (data:view.url not contains "updated-max=")' name='index--first'/>

  <!-- more stuff here -->
</body>
```

Comment: But, it still shows the class `index--first` on pages with the url "updated-max=" !!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a JavaScript method like `indexOf` directly in a Blogger data expression as they are two different languages and run on different sides.

You can do like this

```xml
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
   <script>
      var blogUrl = '<data:blog.url/>';
      var cls = 'index--home';

      <b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
          cls = 'index--label';
      </b:if>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.searchQuery'>
          cls = 'index--query';
      </b:if>

      if (blogUrl.indexOf("search?updated-max") == -1) {
          document.body.classList.add(cls);
      }
   </script>
</b:if>
```

Comment: I was looking for a no JavaScript solution, which is why I didn't add the tag. The use of `indexOf` was just a wild guess, the "if a ternary works, then maybe this works too" kind of thinking. It was not meant to be JavaScript usage.

Comment: Ok, there is a `contains` operator but unfortunately works only with string, array and number data types not url like in `blog.url`

Comment: Do you have an example of it? A link to some docs explaining how to use it? And isn't `blog.url` a string too?

Comment: Here is the [contains operator](https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/2016/04/operator-content.html) The [URL](https://bloggercode-blogconnexion.blogspot.com/2016/04/typeof-URL.html) is a blogger data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this

```
<body>
  <b:class cond='data:view.isHomepage' name='index--first'/>
  <b:class cond='data:view.isPost' name='index--first'/>
  <b:class cond='data:view.isPage' name='index--first'/>
  <b:class cond='data:view.isArchive' name='index--first'/>
  <b:class cond='data:view.search.label' name='index--label'/>
  <b:class cond='data:view.search.query' name='index--query'/>

</body>
```